# Make buttons the same width without specifying the exact size

Tags: html, css

I have five buttons. I want them to take up the available width of their parent div, each being equally sized:

```
<div style="width: 100%; background-color: red;">
    <button type="button" style="width: 20%;">A</button>
    <button type="button" style="width: 20%;">B</button>
    <button type="button" style="width: 20%;">C</button>
    <button type="button" style="width: 20%;">D</button>
    <button type="button" style="width: 20%;">E</button>
</div>
```

Is there a way I can do this without having the manually figure out that they each require 20% width? I want to remove a button at runtime, and that means I have to go and update each remaining button again to width=25%.

I am just checking if there's a more automated way of doing it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The simplest way, and the most robust way, is to use a table:

```
<style>
.buttons { 
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: red; 
}
.buttons button { 
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
<table class=buttons>
 <tr>
    <td><button type="button">A</button>
    <td><button type="button">B</button>
    <td><button type="button">C</button>
    <td><button type="button">D</button>
    <td><button type="button">E</button>
</table>
```

(This won’t improve your reputation among colleagues these days if they see your code, though it actually solves the problem probably better than any alternative. So you might consider doing the next best thing: use `div` markup and `display: table` etc. Fails on old browsers that don’t support such CSS features.)

Comment: Why don't people like this? Is it just a fashion thing?

Comment: @Superbest - Using tables for layout is frowned upon because <table> is a "semantic element" that should only be used for tabular data. Violating semantic elements poses challenges for both web crawlers and screen readers, though there are tricks to determine if a table is being used for layout, such as the absence of <th> and <caption> elements.

Comment: There is really no reason why this use of a <table> could not be classified as using a structural table. (“Semantic elements” are idle babble. A <table> element is not about any meaning, i.e. about semantics. It is about structure, or about layout, or both.) Unless you can point at an actual problem that is caused in real life by this use of a <table> element, I don’t think there is a reason for “semantic” rants that I anticipated in the answer.

Comment: A <table> element absolutely has a semantic meaning. It is for the display of tabular data. That is the "actual problem" with using a table for layout. You could also use spans as divs and assign them all to display:block but it doesn't mean you should. They were used historically for layout but that doesn't mean you should now.

Comment: If I don't use this answer you may find me in a psychiatric asylum.

Comment: A decade late, but this is still the greatest and best answer in the world.

Answer (score 16):

This is my favorite method ([Flexbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout))! -

```
<div style="width: 100%; background-color: red;">
    <button type="button">A</button>
    <button type="button">B</button>
    <button type="button">C</button>
    <button type="button">D</button>
    <button type="button">E</button>
</div>

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
button {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px; /* or whatever you like */
}
```

No matter how many buttons you have, it will resize the button width automatically and fill the `div`.

Working pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YpPdLZ

Comment: Sorry, to inform you but this does not work and the example is just too simple to demonstrate why. Change margin in your sample to 100px and put some really long text into the first button.Buttons will not keep the same size.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I'd tackle a situation like this, taking a queue from front-end grid systems. Use classes! When you remove the button, change the class. [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crowjonah/mrJ5N/).

Your HTML markup could change to this:

```
<div>
    <button type="button" class="fiveup">A</button>
    <button type="button" class="fiveup">B</button>
    <button type="button" class="fiveup">C</button>
    <button type="button" class="fiveup">D</button>
    <button type="button" class="fiveup" id="remove_this">E</button>
</div>
<button id="remove_one">Remove One</button>​
```

CSS like so:

```
.fiveup {width: 18%;margin:1%;float: left;}
.fourup {width: 23%;margin:1%;float: left;}
```

and jQuery like so, though you'll probably want to use this script as part of whatever process removes the button:

```
$('#remove_one').click(function(){
    $('#remove_this').remove();
    $('button').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('fiveup').addClass('fourup');
    });
});​
```

Comment: was just about to post pretty much the same thing ^^ +1

Comment: I really dislike this approach, it's extremely rigid.  What if you have `n` buttons?  And where's your logic to determine what the next class name should be?  And there's a reason we don't do stuff like this: `.red { color:red; }`.

Comment: A 2 case scenario as described in the question is vastly different from an `n` case scenario, and if countless people subscribe to things like the popular [Foundation Framework](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/grid.php), there's got to be a good reason for it.

Answer (score 2):

With bootstrap it is as simple as

```
<div class="btn-group-vertical">

</div>
```

Comment: not everyone uses bootstrap or wants to use bootstrap

Comment: but I am using bootstrap and this was a helpful solution

Answer (score 0):

If we take that their parents are equally sized, you have two solutions to your problem:

CSS:

```
button { /* You may want to limit the selector */
     width: 100%; /* Or any other percent */
}
```

JavaScript (jQuery):

```
$("button").width("100%");
```

Please note, however, that to be sure you also get the exact value, you may want to stick to pixels. If you are willing to use JavaScript, you can also use computed width.

---

**Edit**

If you want to use JavaScript without jQuery, try:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button"),
    i = 0;
for (; i < buttons.length; i++) {
     buttons[i].width = "100%"; //Or any other value
}
```

Note, however, that `.getElementsByTagName()` will have to be replaced if you want a more complex query.

Answer (score -1):

I think, with jQuery, you could do something more dynamic.

The process for the algorithm would be:

1. get the width of the div, put into a variable.
2. divide the width by the number of buttons and put that answer into a variable.
3. run a function that creates a button at that width by however many times required.